# how do I add pagination in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to get the number after the directory `/blog/page/`

I already have `.htaccess` for `blog` folder

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes


RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=307]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I want is in `/blog/page/<get any number here>`

example:

```
www.example.com/blog/page/2
www.example.com/blog/page/3
```

I want to get the number after the `/blog/page/`

Comment: Any [routing layer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing) can do this.

Comment: "I want to get the number after the `/blog/page/`" - And do what with it? The rule you've posted would already pass this in the `url` parameter to `index.php` - so it is up to your PHP script to parse this out. Is that not sufficient? Where is your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Hi, I have htaccess in blog folder and a routing there, but I can`t think of anyway on how to do a pagination with url /blog/page/. Because I need a value after /blog/page/ like a number to query in mysql for my pagination. Should I create another subfolder name page and create htaccess there
or a rewrite rule to add in my existing htaccess in blog folder or a way to get a value after /blog/page/ in a php code?

Comment: "or a way to get a value after /blog/page/ in a php code?" - yes, how are you currently parsing, validating and "routing" the requested URL from the `url` query string parameter?

Comment: thank you , I figured it out using explode. I actually copied a mvc structure but I don`t like to modify it at first but now I have to because I dont want to create another subfolder for a page or categories I just let the code to do it.